# How to push git commit message update to remote repo?

Tags: git

I created a remote branch for me to do work on.  No one else checks into my branch.  I just pushed all my file changes to the remote branch and can see it in the remote.  I forgot to add something else to my commit message so I ran

```
git commit --amend
```

I can see my local branch has my commit additions.

However, when I ran:

```
git push
```

my additional commit message aren't pushed to the remote repo.  What command do I run such that the remote pushes the additional commit message to go with the files I had edited?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+push+amended+commit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Appreciate that when you ran `git commit --amend` you actually made a *new* commit on top of your branch, which completely replaced the previous commit with the former message.  In order to push the branch, you will need to do a force push:

```
git push --force origin feature
```

Keep in mind that amending the commit amounts to *rewriting* the history of the branch.  Doing this can cause problems for others who might be working with that branch, so you should minimize this.